# Longest Calculator Word?

Tags: mathematics, open-ended, language, english

**Current Best; Babingtonites =  5371207621898; 13 letters**

We all know from fooling around with a calculator at some point in our lives, the when we turn a calculator upside down we can make words. *For example, 0.7734 being HELLO. Or 808 being BOB.*

Now assuming your calculator screen can stretch as far as you like, what's the longest word you can possibly spell?

**Numbers on a calculator translate the same as on a digital clock**

**RULES:**

1. Numbers can be used as many times as you like.
2. You cannot use operators (+, -, /, *, etc.) in your word.
3. The decimal sign may only be used once. You can only use it as **A)** a seperator to put 0 at the beginning of the number (to put O at the end of the word) or **B)** an apostrophe.
4. A number can only be used as a single letter in your word, and should not double!

**Accepted answer will change to always be the longest!**

*Note: Please don't ruin the fun by googling!  *

Comment: Not that I'm a hater, but I'd like an explanation as to why this is a bad question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm going to guess people thought it was a bad puzzle because it's way too easy to code the answer. (I bet that's what McMagister did. I would have done it too if I cared about points.)

I would enjoy this puzzle in a live setting, e.g. a pub quiz.

Comment: @Lopsy That shouldn't take away the value of a fun competition!

Comment: What is the point of Rule #2 - words don't have operators.

Comment: @paceoverflow People could try to cheat t with a + sign, or dash with -. See my point?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Babingtonites - 13 letters

> ## $5371207621898$

[Definition](https://www.google.es/search?site=&q=define:+babingtonite#q=define:+babingtonites)
[Accepted on Scrabble](http://www.scrabblewordsolver.com/word-checker/babingtonites)

Comment: A 9 looking like a..?

Comment: a sort of. that's what i intended at least

Comment: Sure, I'll allow it.

Comment: How is that word being displayed? If mirror-imaged, I'd read that as BQBISATOSITES". If rotated 180 degrees, "BbBIgLOZILES".

Comment: Yes, rotated 180º, the 9 is supposed to be an `a`, 1 is `i`, 7 is `t` without cross, which I think has been used in older English writing, 2 is `n`.

Answer (score 14):

### 9 letters

> BIOLOGIES = 531607018

### <s>11 letters</s>

> HELIOLOGIES = 53160701734

Definition: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heliology

### 12 letters

> BIBLIOLOGIES = 531607017818

Definition: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bibliologies
Accepted by Scrabble: http://www.scrabblewordsolver.com/word-checker/bibliologies

Comment: Nice :D Can't wait to see what others come up with.

Comment: Does Heliology make sense plural? (Also my iPod says it isn't a word lol!)

Comment: I can't really find any good source for heliologies so I'm not going to accept it.

Comment: Bibliologies is longer and seems more legit.

Comment: Agreed. Edited as best into question.

Comment: You can also do BOBSLEIGH for 491375808.

Answer (score 2):

**15 Letters**

---

Note: the question doesn't specify explicitly whether the calculator needs to be inverted (although I think it intended it to be).  Also, I'm going to assume my calculator is set to decimal, as it often isn't.

Based on writing the alphabet, here are the letters I think I can reasonably use rightsideup:

> a=0, b=6/8, d=0, e=3, g=9, i=1, l=1, o=0, q=9, s=5, z=2

Note I allow a backwards "E" because of the cultural entrenchment of leetspeak.  Upsidedown:

> a=0, b=8/9, d=0, e=3, g=6, h=4, i=1, l=1/7, o=0, q=6, s=5, t=7, z=2

Since it seems that the set of upsidedown letters is a strict superset of the rightsideup ones, the ambiguity is irrelevant.

---

I have a script I wrote for bruteforce dictionary searches with regexes.  It uses a dictionary stored on my HDD, so there was no Googling, as required.

The longest words `^[abdegiloqsz]{11,99}$` returns are `babesiosises`, `bibliologies`, and `glossolalias`, all 12 letters.  For the upsidedown words, `^[abdeghiloqstz]{15,99}$` gives up `digestibilities`, which is 15 letters.  Therefore, I claim:

> digestibilities = 53171719175361.0

---

N.B. the `i`, `l`, and `t` are mapped by my scheme into `1` and `7`.  By the pigeonhole principle, there's a conflict.  However, if the current answer uses a `9` for an `a` (backwards character), then think probably I should be allowed a `4` for a `t` (one extra stroke).

N.B. if you don't like `digestibilities`, here are some 14-letter words: `diabetologists`, `disestablished`, `disestablishes`, (and more dubiously: `habitabilities`, `illegibilities`, `dilatabilities`).

N.B. If anyone sees how more letters could be added (I'll admit I wasn't very thorough) or wants to give me a more comprehensive dictionary (ASCII; one word per line), I'd be happy to run the search again.

Answer (score 0):

> `assassinations`  (14 letters)
>  `52017921559559`

Accepted [by the Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assassination) (just add an s).

Comment: Using a 2 for the letter n? I don't really see how that works. I see it as a Z, not an N.

Answer (score -1):

> intelligibilities (17)
>   53171119161113721

It is accepted by the Oxford Dictionary 
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intelligibly

Comment: This is probably going to be accepted sooner or later, but please try not to answer multiple times unless the OP doesn't mind — it is a sneaky way to earn extra reputation...